# Bug in Stack Overflow Profile page when viewing other User's Profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, profile-page

I recently noticed that when viewing other user's profile page on SO, its showing up the button "**view my Developer CV**" and on clicking that its taking us to corresponding user's CV page, it seems a BUG to me, it should show **"View Corresponding User's CV"** right !

I am attaching a Screen Shot of my profile page when I am viewing it as a guest , you will notice the text of button on right hand side is showing up as "view my Developer CV".[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is written in first person. The user whose profile you are looking at is inviting you to view their CV.

Comment: oh ok I got that & agreed, But isn't somewhat confusing ? As my collegues who were visiting my profile thought its asking them to view thier CV